# Phantomjs - frames missing for animation

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, phantomjs, frame-rate

I am using phantomjs to generate screenshot from a d3 animation and then merge the screenshots to create a video using ffmpeg. I am using the phantomjs  `render` method  to create series of screenshot. But when render method is used, I have to make the d3 animation extra slow so that all animation is captured smoothly. Even then, there seems to be frames missing. the animation doesnt look that smooth.

So I came across another method, `renderBuffer` which I saw in the documentation of phantomjs. But this method, when tried to execute, even the example code wont execute. I was hoping renderBuffer could solve the missing frame issue.

Anyone else facing similar issue or any methods you guys could suggest to attain smooth continuous frames?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?